# Cannot verify if password is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, ecmascript-6

I am validating a form and I want to show a message when the password is invalid, verified with a RegExp, only if it is not empty, but I am not being able to verify whether the password is empty or not.
This is the piece of code  I am refering.

```
const regexPasswd: RegExp = /((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W]).{8,64})/;
    const inputPasswd = $(form).find("[name='passwd']");
    const passwd;
    let allOK = true;
    if (inputPasswd.val() !== undefined || inputPasswd.val() !== "" || inputPasswd.val() !== null) {
          if (this.regexPasswd.test(<string>inputPasswd.val())) passwd = inputPasswd.val();
          else {
            message += "Invalid Password<br>";
            allOK = false;
          }
        }
```

I have tried all three methods I know to verify an empty input, but still does not work. 
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Should be `&&` operator instead of `||` in your condition.

Comment: `var pwd = $(form).find("[name=passwd]").val() || ""` then check `if (pwd === "")`

Comment: What construct is this? 
`this.regexPasswd.test(<string>inputPasswd.val()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&&` (logical AND) not `||` (logical OR) in your conditional and cache the value:

```
let val = $.trim(inputPasswd.val()); 
if (val !== undefined && val !== "" && val !== null) {...}
```

Comment: No problem @zarzanduil, always glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointed out your mistake about || and &&

However I want to point that HTML provides an easier solution!

First of all, you can add a Required attribute. It will be impossible to submit the form without any content in that field.

Second, you can use minlength to set a minimum required length. However with 1 this is a bit redundant as you got required for this

Hope this helps!

```html
<label for="name">Name (4 to 8 characters):</label>

<form>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="1" maxlength="12" size="12">
       
<input type="submit" value="test">
```

Comment: Sorry friend, I have not have explained myself clear. What I wanted was not to show a message when the password is empty but to show it when checking its format only when it is not empty. I have edited the question now. But thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem! Thanks for not downvoting because it's not what you wanted!

Answer (score -1):

simply write

```
const regexPasswd: RegExp = /((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W]).{8,64})/;
    const inputPasswd = $(form).find("[name='passwd']");
    const passwd;
    let allOK = true;
    if (!inputPasswd.val().length == 0 || inputPasswd.val() )  
    {
     // if value length is non-zero or non-undefined or non-null 

          if (this.regexPasswd.test(<string>inputPasswd.val())) passwd = inputPasswd.val();
          else {
            message += "Invalid Password<br>";
            allOK = false;
          }
        }
```

Comment: `if ($.trim(inputPasswd.val()).length > 0)` makes more sense

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `if (inputPasswd.val() && inputPasswd.val().length !== 0)` ?  - moved the `!` for clarity, but should check if `.va()` is not null before calling `.length` on it otherwise you get an error

Comment: The length property would be OK but I am writing this in a Type Script file

Comment: @freedomn-m FYI! if u write null in an if statement you will get false and also

if (inputPasswd.val() && inputPasswd.val().length !== 0) and (!inputPasswd.val().length == 0 || inputPasswd.val() )  are the same thing

Comment: @DanialShabbir let's test that: `var x = null; if (x.length == 1 || x == null) console.log("it works")` - oh look - is that a `false`?  No, it's an `Uncaught TypeError`.  In javascript, with `||` it runs the left-side test first which in this case gives an error, not null - for completeness, if the left-side of || is `true` then it stops and doesn't run any more (relevant when using functions).

Comment: @zarzanduil maybe next time add Typescript in your question / tags?

Comment: @zarzanduil how the hell in the world are you getting length of `null` ? plus input field return empty string which for your information looks like this '' , if you know, **empty string**. now write your super buggy code with this code then tell me `var x = ''; if (x.length == 1 || x == null) console.log("it works");`
- oh look - it does not return error.


also more for your information, i am not sure about your javascript understanding but if you pass 

`var x = '';if(x){// wont execute}`


`null` or `''` return false in if.. 

Never take length of null!